# Java - API support for traceroute?

Tags: java, linux, windows, traceroute

Is there anyway I can get the output of traceroute in java. I know I could use exec but I want to know if there is any API can fetch the output for me not worrying about platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using the following API :

http://jakewharton.github.io/pingdom-java/apidocs/com/jakewharton/pingdom/entities/TraceRoute.html

GitHub link:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/

Comment: Isn't that a REST ful API? I'm not sure can I use it in a java program. If so can you give an example

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do specifically in a language, i would recommend you to go to the command line and type `tracert www.google.com`,it will give you the desired result